# Get an equation from the relationship among variables

Tags: correlation

I have an agricultural dataset of crop yield (in kilograms) under environmental conditions such as humidity, rainfall, sunlight over few years. I want to find out relationship between the environmental factors and the crop yield.

A score is assigned based on the crop yield each term.

- The closer the environmental conditions to the ideal conditions, higher the crop yield.
- The highest crop yield under ideal conditions is scored as 10.
- For non-ideal environmental conditions, the score can be between 1-10.

The output I'm expecting is an equation which anyone can plug-in the environmental conditions, and get a score between 1-10 on how ideal the conditions are.

Could you help me on choosing an approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem that can be fixed with any regression problem. Here are models I would recommend to get started with:

- If you need your model to be explainable (i.e. show which factors contributed to the score most):

*Decision trees / random forests

Linear regression*

- If you only care about giving a final score

Essentially any other model, which can include:

*Support vector machines

Neural Networks

K-Nearest Neighbours

Gaussian Processes

and more*